# Trying to get substrings for an array of words and to get the substring which meets the palindrome criteria in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#

Hi, 
   I am trying to get all the sub strings for words one by one and then trying to get the palindrome for all those sub strings. Any suggestion, how can I achieve this?

Comment: what u have tried yet ?

Comment: Please post your code what have you done so far.

Comment: Think about writing a function that takes a string and determines if it's a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `List<string>` as collection of words

```
// A simple method to reverse the string
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

Usage:

```
var words = new List<String>();
var palindromes = words.Select(w => Reverse(w)); // this assumes that all the words are palindrome;
```

if you need to check for palindrome before selection then try this

```
var palindromes = words..Where(w => w == Reverse(w)).Select(w => Reverse(w)); // this assumes that all the words are palindrome;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get substrings using for loop and then check whether its palindrome using palindrome function...

Comment: OK... Can you guide me as to how to get different substring of a word for eg: August ...